# Animating transparency in powerpoint

Tags: windows-7, animation, transparency, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

I want to make a picture in a powerpoint slide become more transparent gradually, and then remain so for the rest of that slide's display.

I cannot find an option to animate the transparency process itself, as the timing options only relate to how long the image remains transparent.  It seems the animation immediately transforms the transparency level.

Is there a way to have a picture appear (fly-in animation), then become more transparent (from 0% to 70%) over a period of say, 1 second and then remain transparent while that slide is displayed?

Answer (score 2):

The best thing to do is to make that slide automatically transition after the fade to the *next* slide which has the faded picture as a background. It's a cheat, but the audience won't notice.

It's the same cheat to build a table row-by-row; create the whole table and then delete the bottom rows progressively as you copy the table into preceding slides, and there you have it.

Comment: I'm achieving unachievable with this technique since 1995. :)

Comment: I guess you mean the fade EXIT animation.  OK, but this fades to invisibility, not a mostly transparent image.  So it fades to invisible, transitions, and suddenly reappears as a faded image. I notice it, so I expect the audience will too.  Also, how to automatically transition after an animation effect.  I only see options to transition on mouseclick, or after a certain amount of time.